# Must the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header include scheme?

Tags: http, cors

I'm having some problems with CORS definitions, and I have a question (not about CORS in general - *that* I'm fine with - just about the official specification and usage):

According to the IETF, if the Origin header is passed and if it is a URL, that URL must be fully serialized, and must include scheme and host (and optionally port). From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7.1:

```
The Origin header field has the following syntax:

origin              = "Origin:" OWS origin-list-or-null OWS
origin-list-or-null = %x6E %x75 %x6C %x6C / origin-list
origin-list         = serialized-origin *( SP serialized-origin )
serialized-origin   = scheme "://" host [ ":" port ]
                   ; <scheme>, <host>, <port> from RFC 3986
```

At least, I think I have understood that correctly.

The IETF *also* says that the format of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must follow the same format. From http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" ":" origin-list-or-null | "*"
```

and links to the Origin header page.

However, I have seen numerous examples (both here on SO and elsewhere) which show ACAO headers *without* the scheme (i.e. not an exact 'mirror' of the Origin header), e.g. they show this being passed in the request:

```
Origin: http://www.example.com
```

and this as the 'correct' response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.example.com
```

So is that ACAO header valid? I thought that the ACAO header had to be an exact mirror of the Origin header value (or '*' or 'null').

If I respond with an ACAO header which *doesn't* include the scheme, should the User Agent accept it? Or is it on a UA-by-UA basis? What if the Origin includes a port number - do I need to include that in the ACAO response header, with or without the scheme?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you mentionned, [RFC 6454](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7.1) define the syntax of an origin without ambiguity:

```
origin              = "Origin:" OWS origin-list-or-null OWS
origin-list-or-null = %x6E %x75 %x6C %x6C / origin-list
origin-list         = serialized-origin *( SP serialized-origin )
serialized-origin   = scheme "://" host [ ":" port ]
```

and [CORS W3C recommandation](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) explicity refer to the same definition.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" ":" origin-list-or-null | "*"
```

So the following header **is not valid**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.example.com
```

and **must not be accepted by User Agent**

> When generating an Origin header field, the user agent MUST meet the
> following requirements:

> Each of the serialized-origin productions in the grammar MUST be
> the ascii-serialization of an origin.

This is particularly important because of the [same-origin policy](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-abarth-principles-of-origin-00):

> The same-origin policy is one of the cornerstones of security for
> many user agents, including web browsers.

Concerning the second part of the question about the port the number, the [ASCII serialization of an origin algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-6.1) states:

> 5. If the port part of the origin triple is different from the
>    default port for the protocol given by the scheme part of the
>    origin triple:
>
> Append a U+003A COLON code point (":") and the given port, in base ten, to result.

Comment: Still confused. If I want to build a list of two, for example, `www.example.com` and `www.example.net`, what should I write after `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:`? Can you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: @cmal you should first validate the _Origin_ Request header is www.example.com or www.example.net and respond back with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <whichever_was_in_the_Origin_request_header>

Comment: TLDR: it must include URL scheme.